# Non Deduced context for a non type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates

I am reading C++ Templates (2nd edition) and this is a snippet from the book:

```
template<typename... Ts, int N>
void f(double (&)[N+1], Ts... ps) {return;}
```

It is specified in the book that the declaration above is useless because N cannot be specified or deduced.

I am trying to understand why something like the following is an error:

```
double arr[2];
f<int, double, 1>(arr, 1, 2.0);
```

When I compile the snippet above, I get the error that there is no matching function for call to f.

This compiles fine

```
template<typename... Ts, typename T> 

void func(T value){}; 
func(1);
```

even though I have an additional parameter after a parameter pack.

Why does my specifying of the template arguments explicitly not match the arguments provided? Please help me understand this.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - Hmmm...This compiles fine - template<typename... Ts, typename T> void func(T value){}; func(1); even though I have an additional parameter after a parameter pack.

Once again, my question here is different from the one you have linked to as I am not asking the compiler to do the deduction but I am helping it with the deduction. Need to understand why that fails.

Comment: Clang gives this notice "candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Ts'". The invocation `f<int, double>(arr, 1, 2.0)` compiles succesfully! So is `f(arr, 1, 2.0)`. So it seems `N` can be deduced, at least in g++ and clang++.

Comment: @CygnusX1....sorry my bad...i have edited the question....it is actually N+1 and not N....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fact that N cannot be deduced has nothing to do with the parameter pack. This doesn't compile either because N cannot be deduced.

```
template<int N>
void f(double (&)[N+1]) {}

int main() {
    double arr[2];
    f(arr);
}
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) (Non-deduced contexts):

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>   [...]
>   3) A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a subexpression references a template parameter

The fact that N cannot be specified has a different cause: the standard says that you simply cannot specify a parameter placed after a parameter pack.

From [temp.param]:

> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
>   by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the *parameter-type-list*
>   of the function template or has a default argument (14.8.2). *[Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T1 = int, class T2> class B;    // error
>
> // U can be neither deduced from the parameter-type-list nor specified
> template<class... T, class... U> void f() { }  // error
> template<class... T, class U> void g() { }     // error
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697055/are-multiple-non-type-template-parameter-packs-allowed) from which I got the quote)

Your other example works because `T` can be deduced from the parameters.

```
template<typename... Ts, typename T> 
void func(T value){}; 
func(1); // 1 is used to deduce T
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nelfeal. That answers the question perfectly.